# How do I make a text channel when the bot enters the server and when it detects there is not pre existing server with the channel name

Tags: discord.py

I am making a private dm bot. I am trying to make the bot make a text channel when the bot joins the server called "private-dm" with the properties of "@everyone: read past messages = False" So it is private and when the bot doesn't see already see a channel names private-dm just in case the bot goes offline. I couldn't find any on_bot_join event in the docs and I also couldn't find anything to make a text channel when it has not detected any with the given name.

Answer (score 0):

`on_bot_join` is known as [`on_guild_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=join#discord.on_guild_join).

For the second issue you can just loop over all existing channels using [`Guild.text_channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channels#discord.Guild.text_channels) & check if any of them has that name. If not, make it.

Comment: Can you give me the code for the second part I couldnt figure it out, and also how do I change the properties so no one else can read the past messages?

Comment: Could you at least do an attempt at trying it yourself first, and posting the code you tried, and saying where you had issues?

As for those permissions (not properties), the docs even have an example for that: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.Guild.create_text_channel

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for "read past messages" not read messages. The other part I tried but I couldnt figure out which event to put it in. I tried putting it in on ready but I didnt get the check working.

Comment: The docs is just an example... If you want another permission, then change it to the one you want, which in your case is `read_message_history`

Comment: ok I got that part working. Then how do I do the 2nd part. I couldnt figure out how to loop over the pre existing channels.

Comment: I told you in my reply how to get a list of all the channels, so looping over them is just a `for`-loop. Again, at least try it first, and post your code & ask questions where you got stuck, not just asking people to send you the code.